# adding a class to a specific image

Tags: jquery, xml

I am having a slight no-brainer today and was wondering if someone could help me out here...

I am parsing an XML to a JavaScript which is working perfectly...

The XML looks something like this

```
<test>
    <part background="images/background.png">
        <mark image="images/image1.png"></mark>
        <mark image="images/image2.png"></mark>
    </part>
</test>
```

in my JavaScript i have something like this:

```
$(xml).find('test'>.each(function(){
  var screen = $('<div class="screen"></div>').appendTo(container);
  var list = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo(screen);

$(xml).find('part').each(function() {
   var part = $('<li></li>').appendTo(list);
   part.append($('<img/>).attr('src', $(this).attr('background')));

$(this).find('mark').each(function() {
  var mark = $('<div></div>').appendTo(part);
  mark.append($('<img/>').attr('src', $(this).attr('image')));
```

Now what i would like to do is to give `image2.png` a css class but as I said before I am having a nobrainer today, therefore could someone tell me the easiest way of achieving this. Thanks in advance to the person who can help me out.

Comment: so are you looking to give a particular child node index a class? or any image2.png references a css class?

Comment: Also keep in mind, by using `.find()` in such a way, you aren't limiting it to the current parent node of `test`.  I suspect this will throw you off right after you resolve your current issue.  Once you are in a node, you can use `$(this).children('part').each()` (or if inside a part node, then use `$(this).children('mark').each()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?:

```
if ($(this).attr('image') == "image2.png") {
    mark.append($('<img src="'+$(this).attr('image')+'" class="foo">');
} else {
    mark.append($('<img/>').attr('src', $(this).attr('image')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('img[src$="image2.png"]').addClass('theClass');
```

as last command of your script (after all appends)

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
if ($(this).attr('src') == "images/image2.png") {
 mark.addClass('class')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this (mark section):

```
$(this).find('mark').each(function() {
    var mark = $('<div></div>').appendTo(part);
    //Example 1
    mark.append($('<img/>').attr({'src':$(this).attr('image'), 'class':($(this).attr('image')==='image2.png')?'class-name':''}));

    //Example 2
    var img = $('<img/>').attr('src', $(this).attr('image'));
    if($(this).attr('image') === 'image2.png')
        img.addClass('class-name');
    mark.append(img);
});
```